# Does Xから modify Yの here?

Tags: grammar

From [the Wikipedia article for 源頼朝](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%BA%90%E9%A0%BC%E6%9C%9D):

> 源頼朝は、平安時代末期から鎌倉時代初期の武将、政治家であり、鎌倉幕府の初代征夷大将軍である。

Clearly, 平安時代末期から鎌倉時代初期の modifies 武将、政治家. However, what does the 平安時代末期から modify? Is 鎌倉時代初期の treated as a の-adjective here, grammatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume you have the basic knowledge discussed in this question:
[Why can we use の after へ and から?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27363/5010)

In short, 平安時代末期から is like an adverb and modifies a *verb*. 平安時代末期から**の** is like an adjective and modifies a *noun*.

> - 平安時代から**の**武将 a bushō from the Heian period (say he's a time traveler)
> - 平安時代から知られている to be known from the Heian period
> - 月へ**の**旅行 a journey to the moon
> - 月から**の**帰還 a return from the moon
> - 月へ旅行する to travel to the moon

When two or more phrases modify the same *noun*, usually such の is *not* omitted:

> - 僕と**の**月へ**の**旅行 a journey with me to the moon
> - 月へ**の**僕と**の**旅行 a journey to the moon with me
> - カナダから**の**重要な手紙 an important letter from Canada

However, since から and まで/へ are used together very frequently, AからBまで or AからBへ is treated as one set, and the の after から is usually omitted:

> - 地球から月へ**の**旅行 a journey from the earth to the moon
> - カナダから日本まで**の**チケット a ticket from Canada to Japan

In your example, there is no まで after 鎌倉時代初期, but I feel inserting まで there is somewhat out of place, or at least redundant.

So I think this 平安時代末期から modifies nothing by itself, but it modifies the noun phrase "武将、政治家" when it's coupled with の.

> - 平安時代から**の**武将 (modifies a noun)
> - 平安時代から鎌倉時代**の**武将 (modifies a noun; の after から is omitted because it's the "from A to/till B" pattern)
> - 平安時代から**の**秘密**の**武将 (modifies a noun; の must *not* be omitted)
> - 平安時代から現代に来た武将 (modifies a verb 来る)