# what does kara no mean?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, particle-から

Sometimes instead of "kara" which I understand it mostly translates as "from" I see written "kara no", which it seems to have a similar meaning to "kara" alone. What's the difference or what does it mean? Here it's the specific case

"Yūsha Satan yo kiseki o okose! Uchū kara no chōsenjō!!"

Comment: This is 'no' modifying 'kara'. Many particles can be combined with 'no' to modify kara in the same way that no modifies nouns.
nihongo no sensei is a teacher of Japanese. Uchuu kara no chousenjo is a 'Written challenge (that comes) from the universe'.

Comment: *No* is not modifying *kara*.  Japanese is a strictly head-final language.

Comment: @james edwards . I dont understand what you mean . "Uchū kara no chōsenjō" is translated as "a challenge from the universe". What does that "no" adds here? Why it isn't just written "Uchū kara chōsenjō" since "kara" means "from" ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Why can we use の after へ and から?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27363/542)

Comment: 'Kara' modifies a verb later in the sentence, 'kara no' modifies the following noun.