# の function in 以上の

Tags: translation, particle-の

I found it in これ以上のおしゃべりは.
My question is, why 以上の is translated as no more. It it because の have a specific function here? or it is just an expression.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「これ以上のおしゃべりは。」 is the entire sentence, right?

の here is a particle that is grammatically required to link ～以上/から/まで/だけ/etc and a noun. See: [Why can we use の after へ and から?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27363/5010)

> - 100円以上のお金 money more than 100 yen
> - 明日からの仕事 tasks from tomorrow
> - 3人だけの会社 a firm with only three people

So your sentence, 「これ以上のおしゃべりは。」 literally means "Chatting more than that is...", with the last part of the sentence omitted because it's obvious. The omitted phrase would be 禁止です, やめよう, 良くない, するな, or such.

You may occasionally hear "これ以上は…。" in conversations. It literally means "More than this is..." but it usually means "I've had enough", "No more, please", etc.

Comment: Thanks, that's make perfectly clear. It's challenging enough without the need to guess the rest of the sentence