# There is not enough space

Tags: phrases

I have a query about how to say "there is no enough space for it?" and "it's in the way."

Unfortunately my japanese is not good enough to create a natural sentence, and all I come out with is

> それのために場所がありません。

which I believe doesn't really explain what I'm trying to say and might be actually wrong. (I apologize in advance for it).

Comment: Enough space for what? Depending on what it is, the phrase will change a lot (leaving something in a room, putting something in a schedule, doing some extra task, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mistake you made is that you said ために instead of ための. The correct sentence is:

> それのため**の**場所がありません。

ために is adverbial (modifies a verb) and ための is adjectival (modifies a noun). Obviously you want それのため to modify 場所 (noun) right after it, so you should use の.

See:

- [Why can we use の after へ and から?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27363/5010)
- [using の with と,で, から, まで](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33605/5010)

In addition, それのため is a bit wordy; you can simply say そのため.

> そのための場所がありません。

If you want to explicitly say "enough", use 十分 (na-adjective):

> そのための十分な場所がありません。

---

P.S. You don't have to apologize for making an incorrect sentence, but [we don't do general proofreading](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799). Next time please specify the grammatical point you are most concerned about.