# Confusion with meaning when の particle in 行ってからの楽しみとしておく is used

Tags: grammar, particle-の

I came across a bit of dialog in a game that I'm struggling to understand

> まぁ、名前の由来はそうだな…。今教えると楽しみが減るだろうから**行ってからの楽しみとしておく**のがいいだろう。

I don't really understand how to translate 行ってからの楽しみとしておくas a whole. I know that 行ってから is "after going do X" and I assume 楽しみとしておく is "keep it as fun". But I'm not entirely sure how the の particle translates to English in this. I want to translate 行ってからの楽しみ as "the fun after going" or "after going's fun", but that feels very wrong when combined with the rest of the sentence.

How is the の particle supposed to translate and go along with the sentence as a whole?

My translation:

> Anyway, That's the name's origin. If I were to tell you now, I think it would be less fun. So I think it would be good to keep up the fun after going

Context:
A research facility has made breakthrough in their research. After a small explanation, a team member of my group asks "If you've reached an understanding about the locations in general, does that mean you know where the other artifacts are located?" The question is more or less overlooked for a bit until the above dialog is stated

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48424/45489

Comment: Possible dup https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33605/45489

Comment: I understand that the の particle connects `行ってから` and `楽しみとしておく`, the distinction of it in English is very difficult though. I'm assuming `行ってからの楽しみとしておく` is better translated as "keep it as fun, which is (earned / gained) after going". I guess as a whole in English it is: `Anyway, That's the name's origin. If I were to tell you now, I think it would be less fun. So I think it would be good to keep as something fun, which is had after going`

Comment: I think you get the meaning. Basically it is saying *let's have the fun later.*

Comment: BTW そうだな here means *well..*, so the starting sentence is *The name's origin? well...*

Comment: Is `そうだな` a set phrase that ends up as "well..."? I would have assumed it to be something like "that's what I've heard" or "it seems to be the case". Which is how I got "that's (seems to be) the name's origin". In the previous dialog prompt the persons states "我々は超古代の海と呼ぶことにしたんだ。(We decided to call it the super ancient ocean.)"

Comment: [そうだな](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0%E3%81%AA) can means various things depending on the context. Here it is used more as an interjection. As a response (in different context), it could be *yes that is true/so*.